# Posting only for fields that contain a value in Webmatrix

Tags: razor, webmatrix

I've created a search page, which searches my database depending on parameters set in query string parameters. The search page works great, but as I look to add more and more search parameters in, I don't want the URL to be filled with blank query strings.

Say I have a form with 10 search options, but only want to specify 2, is it possible to only post these 2 to the URL rather than all 10?

Comment: also, i must add, that i'm not currently using AJAX to post this form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if you use JavaScript to make the request. You don't even need a form for this. Here's a simple example that uses jQuery for the JavaScript (to simplify things):

```
@{

}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('button').click(function () {
                    var url = [location.protocol, '//', location.host, location.pathname].join('');
                    var queryAdded = false;
                    $('input[type=text]').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).val() != '') {
                            url += queryAdded ? '&' : '?';
                            url += $(this).prop('name') + '=' + $(this).val();
                            queryAdded = true;
                        }
                    });
                    location.href = url;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            @Html.TextBox("field1")
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.TextBox("field2")
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.TextBox("field3")
        </div>
        <div>
            <button>Click</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great, thanks Mike. It all makes sense, but can you just explain what the ".join('')" part does?

Comment: It combines the elements of an array into a string using the specified delimiter (or a comma if none is specified). See here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

Comment: ok great. so i'm able to get the page to post to itself, but i'm trying to modify the url variable, for it to post to a different page, and i'm having zero luck. I've tried removing the array (not sure why you'd use an array to build a URL?) and substituted for a string "www.facebook.com" for eg, and that doesn't work either?

Comment: The `hostname` will resolve to 'stackoverflow.com/' on this site. The `pathname` will resolve to 'questions/...' on this page. So if you want to post to Page2.cshtml in your existing site, replace 'location.pathname' with 'Page2.cshtml'

Comment: i've edited you code above to remove the pathname, and include "contact.cshtml" which is where i want to submit the querystring parameters, but it's not working?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What code are you trying to use and what result do you get?

Comment: Oh - I see you attempted to edit the code in my answer and it was rejected. You should put contact.cshtml in quotes: `var url = [location.protocol, '//', location.host, 'contact.cshtml'].join('');`

Comment: If i do that, the form sends me to a blank page (about:blank) with no querystrings at all?

Comment: Change the `url` line to this: `var url = location.protocol +  '//' + location.host + '/contact.cshtml';`

Comment: superb :) thanks for your help, this makes my like MUCH easier